# "..so that others may live", future subjunctive?

Tags: conjunctive, purpose-clause

Salvete, omnes:

I studied Latin in college, but it has been a few years since I was immersed in it. I'm trying to wrangle a translation for the motto of an American Air Force search & rescue unit:

> These things I do, so that others may live.

My attempt so far:

> Haec facio, ut alios... (?)

Pretty straightforward in English, but now I think I'm remembering that Latin has no future subjunctive mood. "I do X, so that Y may happen in the future."

How would you render this verb indicating future purpose?

Answer (score 10):

This is a simple purpose clause, and so you'll want to the present subjective, *ut alii vivant*. (Note that you'll want to turn the accusative *alios* into the nominative *alii* since it's the subject of the purpose clause.) There's already a future aspect to the subjunctive present, so there's no need for further differentiation.

For more information, check out Allen and Greenough [§ 531.1](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/allen-greenough/Chapters/Chapter-531.html), with the example given:

> *ab arātrō abdūxērunt Cincinnātum, ut dictātor esset* (*Fin*. 2.12), they brought Cincinnatus from the plough that he might be dictator.

Comment: For some reason I read "so that others may live" more like *ut alii vivere possint* than *ut alii vivant*. Do you think *posse* would be an idiomatic addition?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I don't think there's any need for that at all. It depends on what you're emphasizing. See Allen and Greenough § 531.1: "ab arātrō abdūxērunt Cincinnātum, ut dictātor esset (Fin. 2.12), they brought Cincinnatus from the plough that he might be dictator."